# Is it possible to use plafyramework2 for java with groovy template?

Tags: java, scala, groovy, playframework, playframework-2.0

Is it possible to use `plafyramework2` for java with groovy template?

I found that `play 2` for `scala` is not ready for production yet. (I wish it was [`ide` support issue, slowness]). But this reason I would not use scala templates as well but groovy one.

So, is there a way to manage this? To integrate old-good groovy templates with new Play2 API with "old good" `java`?

Answer (score 2):

There is a module for using Groovy templates in a PlayFramework 2 application : https://github.com/manuelbernhardt/play2-groovy-templates

You will find documentation on its dedicated Github repository.

Comment: gonna test it. hope it's in working state. maybe that's quite good/fast to be with scala + groovy template. hoping.

Comment: there is related link I found: http://kjetland.com/blog/2011/11/playframework-new-faster-groovy-template-engine/   fast groovy template. not sure what is better